# Web scraping a .htm page with <pre> preformatted text and no tags

Tags: python, html, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a newbie working on a web scraping project. I need to get these election results into a dataframe (or Excel) in order to analyze it.

What's been most tricky is that it is a .htm file with all the data as one big text block in between "Preformatted Text" (PRE) tags, and no individual tags on the data itself. I am only interested in the parts of the data that are set up like tables:

https://www.stlouisco.com/portals/8/docs/document%20library/elections/eresults/el140805/EXEC.htm

I have been attempting it in Python with BeautifulSoup. However, if you view the source code at the URL, you can see why BeautifulSoup isn't getting me very far -- because the data isn't structured using tags. The structure looks like this, basically:

```
<html>
<pre>
COUNTY EXECUTIVE                                  PRIMARY ELECTION                                   OFFICIAL FINAL RESULTS
                                              ST. LOUIS COUNTY, MISSOURI
RUN DATE:08/18/14 01:20 PM                        TUESDAY, AUGUST 5, 2014
                                              STATISTICS
                                                                 WITH 681 OF 681 PRECINCTS REPORTING
                                               TOTAL  PERCENT                                                       TOTAL  PERCENT
   01 = REGISTERED VOTERS - TOTAL                661,393             05 = BALLOTS CAST - LIBERTARIAN                 1,121     .58
   02 = BALLOTS CAST - TOTAL                     192,495             06 = BALLOTS CAST - CONSTITUTION                  314     .16 
   03 = BALLOTS CAST - DEMOCRATIC                129,918   67.49     07 = BALLOTS CAST - NONPARTISAN                 6,225    3.23
   04 = BALLOTS CAST - REPUBLICAN                 54,917   28.53     08 = VOTER TURNOUT - TOTAL                              29.10
                                     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                                       01    02    03    04    05    06    07    08
                                     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
0101 AP1,2,7,43                      1317 . 298 . 214 .  69 . . 3 . . 1 .  11 22.63
0103 AP3,27 NRW2,8,15,29             1453 . 186 . 179 . . 5 . . 1 . . 0 . . 1 12.80
0104 AP4                              231 .  51 .  34 . . 4 . . 0 . . 0 .  13 22.08
0105 AP5,18,21,39                    1289 . 268 . 198 .  47 . . 4 . . 1 .  18 20.79
0106 AP6                                2 . . 1 . . 0 . . 0 . . 0 . . 0 . . 1 50.00
0108 AP8,20                           586 . 142 .  86 .  44 . . 4 . . 0 . . 8 24.23
0109 AP9,25                           533 . 119 .  85 .  29 . . 2 . . 3 . . 0 22.33
0110 AP10                            1044 . 158 . 114 .  34 . . 2 . . 0 . . 8 15.13

...

2832 WH32,38,44                       296 .  51 .  23 .  28 . . 0 . . 0 . . 0 17.23
2834 WH34,43                         2043 . 609 . 267 . 321 . . 1 . . 0 .  20 29.81
2835 WH35                             543 . 173 .  60 . 110 . . 0 . . 0 . . 3 31.86
    ====================================================================================================================================
              (DEMOCRATIC)                                           WITH   681 OF 681  REPORTING
                                               VOTES  PERCENT                                                    VOTES  PERCENT
COUNTY EXECUTIVE
  (Vote for )  1
   01 = CHARLIE A. DOOLEY                         39,038   30.52
   02 = STEVE STENGER                             84,993   66.46     03 = RONALD E. LEVY                             3,862    3.02
                                   ------------------
                                       01    02    03
                                   ------------------
0101 AP1,2,7,43                        59   134    19
0103 AP3,27 NRW2,8,15,29              154    18     5
0104 AP4                                7    25     2
0105 AP5,18,21,39                      55   133     9
0106 AP6                                0     0     0
0108 AP8,20                            28    50     7
0109 AP9,25                            21    57     6
0110 AP10                              56    54     1
0111 AP11,24                           53    54     1
0112 AP12                              19    41     1
0113 AP13                              23    46     2
0114 AP14,15,16 NOR31                  25    56     4

...

2819 WH19,20,22                        25   162     7
2825 WH25                              17   109     9
2831 WH31                              18   112     7
2832 WH32,38,44                         0    22     1
2834 WH34,43                           31   218    10
2835 WH35                              16    41     3
====================================================================================================================================
                  (REPUBLICAN)                                           WITH 681 OF 681  REPORTING
                                               VOTES  PERCENT
COUNTY EXECUTIVE
  (Vote for )  1
   01 = TONY POUSOSA                              16,439   32.10
   02 = RICK STREAM                               34,772   67.90
                                   ------------
                                       01    02
                                   ------------
0101 AP1,2,7,43                        24    37
0103 AP3,27 NRW2,8,15,29                1     4
0104 AP4                                1     3
0105 AP5,18,21,39                      13    28
0106 AP6                                0     0
0108 AP8,20                            16    28
0109 AP9,25                             9    19
0110 AP10                              13    19
0111 AP11,24                            7    32

...

</pre>
<p>Some closing text that is irrelevant to this project.</p>
</html>
```

I am hoping to use Python to automate this process so I can run it on other similar webpages of election results.

Here is as far as I've been able to get. I was able to create a list of objects with each list item being one line of the data. I would like it to become a data frame with all the extra spaces and periods stripped out. I'm not sure how to do that from here, though. I imagine I may even be thinking about this from the wrong angle.

```
# STEP 1: Importing the Libraries

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# STEP 2: Collecting and Parsing the webpage

# Collect the election results page
page = requests.get('https://www.stlouisco.com/portals/8/docs/document%20library/elections/eresults/el140805/EXEC.htm')

# Parse the page and create a Beautiful Soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')


# STEP 3: Create an object with just the text
soup2 = soup.text

# Split the text at each line break \n; this creates a list object
[x.strip() for x in soup2.split('\n')]


Output: 

[...
'0212 BON12                           1678 . 685 . 376 . 295 . . 1 . . 0 .  13 40.82',
'0213 BON13,23,26,29                  2174 . 796 . 500 . 261 . . 3 . . 2 .  30 36.61',
'0214 BON14                             17 . . 4 . . 0 . . 0 . . 0 . . 0 . . 4 23.53',
'0215 BON15                           1340 . 369 . 224 . 129 . . 2 . . 1 .  13 27.54',
'0216 BON16                            204 . 104 .  68 .  36 . . 0 . . 0 . . 0 50.98',
'0217 BON17                            589 .  93 .  71 .  16 . . 1 . . 0 . . 5 15.79',
'0218 BON18                            195 .  48 .  28 .  17 . . 0 . . 1 . . 2 24.62',
'0219 BON19 CLA15                     1340 . 443 . 255 . 172 . . 5 . . 0 .  11 33.06',
...]
```

I feel stuck and I would greatly appreciate any advice! (And if Python isn't the best way to automate getting this into a dataframe... I welcome that feedback too.) Thank you.

Comment: Try changing `'html.parser'` to `html5lib` in BeautiflulSoup. Surely you will notice a massive change. First do this `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html5lib')` and then `print(soup)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion SIM. Unfortunately, I ran it like you said and it was almost exactly the same - the data still is just a big text block sitting between <pre> </pre>. (It is not structured using tags.) Appreciate your help, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looking at the example you've cited, you'll need to write a parser since your data is complex and varies across each line (and most likely, each page).**

Using this line as an example, hopefully I can explain why:

```
0101 AP1,2,7,43                      1317 . 298 . 214 .  69 . . 3 . . 1 .  11 22.63
```

1. This part: `0101` is relatively consistent across each line, as this appears to be some sort of integer index that's zero-padded. This is followed by 1 space.
2. However, the next portion (`AP1,2,7,43`) follows certain rules but its content varies. For e.g., we know that the number of comma-separated values varies across each line, and that the values sometimes it can contain whitespace (e.g. `AP3,27 NRW2,8,15,29`). This is then followed by a lot of whitespace up to the next section - i.e. what appears to be voting numbers.
3. For these columns of numbers / integers, each column is separated by a whitespace followed by a combined separator of a dot and a space. If the integers are less than 10, the number is padded such that the `". "` delimiter is repeated and placed in the hundreds position.
4. The last column, `22.63` is a regular floating point number with 2 decimal places.

**This does not yet touch the other lines which each have their own rules.**

Given the complexity of your dataset, you're better off writing a simple grammar using tools like [pyparsing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing/2.2.0) or [PLY](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ply/3.10) to create mini-parsers that can automatically extract the information from each line, which can then be placed in a data-structure and saved to a dataframe. A good example using pyparsing which is applicable here, shows [how to parse street addresses](http://web.archive.org/web/20180718212017/http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/streetAddressParser.py). [More examples can be found here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180718210826/http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples).

**Notably, all of this could be dealt with by writing custom text manipulation functions and code, but given that you intend to automate things, a parser is your best bet since it will be reusable and more adaptable.**

Comment: This explanation is super clear. You've given me an on-ramp to creating what I need! Thank you so much for clarifying my situation and sharing some tools with me - I will be digging in very soon.

Comment: @mindexplore: Not a prob, happy to help - and, thank you as well! I hope you make progress with your project as it looks rather interesting - St. Louis would definitely benefit greatly from it!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the file format, I think this should be pretty doable. The lines you need seem to have a fixed character size. If you read each line, you can split them on character length.

first 5 characters: number (e.g. 0101)

next 32 characters: description (e.g. AP3,27 NRW2,8,15,29           )

next 6 characters: column 01

and so on.
But keep in mind if the format of this file changes, your code will be broken.